# How to create a 3D mesh from an .mb file?

Tags: 3d, maya

I download a 3d model from the internet and I would like to create a 3D mesh from it for a school project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.mb or Maya binary files are proprietary to Autodesk. There is a python library called [cgkit](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/) that implements simple maya binary structure reader, unfortunately it does not understand anything special about the data itself as it may be subject of arbitrary change by Autodesk. But saves you the effort of chunking the file yourself.

Cgkit does however have a bit higher understanding of Maya ASCII files, as well as some other files. So by far the easiest way would be to just ship the .mb file to somebody with Maya and have them convert it to you into Maya ASCII (.ma). Provided that the file does not contain references to any foreign plugin this is basically a read in write out operation. If however the .mb file has data that needs some specific plugin, then it is perfectly possible,  but a unlikely, that only the original author can use the retrieve the data.